# How to install rstudio with conda

Tags: rstudio, anaconda3

[Anaconda Navigator home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQBYg.png)

I am new to this whole process of working with conda, so forgive me in advance.

I am attempting to download and run r-studio through the anaconda navigator software. Every tutorial I see online simply starts with the prompt on their home screen to download r-studio, but that prompt does not exist for me, and I there is no mention of how to get r-studio to appear in this landing page.

I opened an anaconda prompt and attempted to run a download manually for r-studio, but I keep getting this error:

(R-Programming) C:\Users\Chance>conda install -c r rstudio                                                              Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done                                                               Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.                                    Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.             Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done                                                                       Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Until it inevitably crashes.

I am not sure of what information you may need about my system to help me find a solution, so instead of posting a million error messages that might be related, if the answer isn't obvious, I will give info as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the tutorials are mentioning about installing the R studio after opening conda is the best solution. Try reinstalling the Anaconda again. I wonder if any file got corrupt when you installed it.

When you open the "Anaconda Navigator" you should be getting a screen like this below: [Anaconda Navigator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiI4c.png)

When you click on RStudio it should work. For more documentation please check this https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/